# Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable

Tags: python, azure-databricks

Running into issue while registering user defined function in spark using python code, it throws error message "*Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation*"

Here is code snippet.

```
    %python

    def checkColumnNames(columnName,inputFilePath):
      filePath = inputFilePath
      data = spark.read.parquet(filePath)
      columnNames = data.limit(1).columns
      toreturn = 0
      if columnName in columnNames:
        toreturn = 1
      else:
        toreturn = 0

      return (toreturn)

    sqlContext.udf.register("checkColumnNames", checkColumnNames)
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: I suspect the issue here is that you cannot include `spark.read.parquet` in this function, as that means serializing the `SparkContext`

Comment: is there any alternate for spark.read.parquet ?

Comment: Why do you want to register this function in the first place?